# jQuery Accordion Show only the Div that has a Particular Control Inside in it

Tags: jquery, accordion, webforms

i want to show only the div that has a paticular control available otherwise all the other divs are hidden;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= buttonRegister.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var control = $('#<%= TextBoxDateOfAdmission.ClientID %>');
            var admissionValue = control.val();
            if (admissionValue == '') {
                // hide all the divs
                $(".wizard_menu div.wizard_body").hide();
                // i want to show only the div that has a control with id=TextBoxDateOfAdmission
                $('.wizard_menu div.wizard_body')
                                    .has(control).length ? $(".wizard_menu div.wizard_body").show() : $(".wizard_menu div.wizard_body").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** i can't paste my html code becuase it is too long. I have 5 divs with a `class=wizard_menu` 
I have also tested my code using this in-order to prove if it works

```
$('.wizard_menu div.wizard_body')
         .has(control).length ? alert("true") : alert("false");
```

And the result was true; 
**So, Now i want to show the div only that has a particular control(in this case TextBoxDateOfAdmission)  available inside in it** 
**Update:** the result of my code is that it shows all the divs expanded. However, i want only one div expanded or show which has a particular control available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, using the .show() directly;

```
 $('.wizard_menu div.wizard_body')
                .has(control)
                .show();
```